# Terraform for_each?

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-rm, azure-vm-templates

I have been working on this terraform azure vm template and the goal is use for_each to make the module more dynamic in nature but i'm not able to figure out how to reference one resource_id in another resource block.

If you see in first resource block i'm creating NICs using "for_each" and i want to reference the "network_interface_id" in second resource which is associating  Network Interface to outbound load balancer. Not sure how to do that but started to construct the string using variables. can anyone help me on how to reference the "network_interface_id" or any other resource id if required, any help is highly appreciated.

```
###################
# Network Interface
###################

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "this" {

  for_each = var.vm_details
  name = format(
    "%s-${var.location}-%s-%s-nic-%s",
    var.app_acronym,
    var.env,
    var.app_purpose,
    each.value.vm_identifier
  )
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  tags     = var.tags
  ip_configuration {
    name = format(
    "%s-${var.location}-%s-%s-ip-%s",
    var.app_acronym,
    var.env,
    var.app_purpose,
    each.value.vm_identifier
    )
    subnet_id                     = var.subnet_id
    private_ip_address_allocation = var.private_ip_address_allocation != "" ? var.private_ip_address_allocation : "Dynamic"
  }
  enable_accelerated_networking   = each.value.enable_accelerated_networking
}

###########################################################
# Asssociating  Network Interface to outbound load balancer
###########################################################
resource "azurerm_network_interface_backend_address_pool_association" "this" {
  for_each = var.olb_association
  network_interface_id    = "${var.rsrc_id_str_1}${var.subscription_id}${var.rsrc_id_str_2}${var.resource_group_name}${var.rsrc_id_str_nic_3}${var.app_acronym}${var.hifen}${var.location}${var.hifen}${var.env}${var.hifen}${var.app_purpose}${var.nic_abbrv}${each.value.vm_identifier}"
  ip_configuration_name   = format(
    "%s-${var.location}-%s-%s-ip-%s",
    var.app_acronym,
    var.env,
    var.app_purpose,
    each.value.vm_identifier
    )
  backend_address_pool_id = each.value.backend_address_pool_id
  depends_on = [azurerm_network_interface.this]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

`for_each` creates a data structure that is referenced like the map you feed it. So if the name for an entry is "puppy", you would reference it as `azurerm_network_interface.this["puppy"]`

Comment: this will only work for one entry, what if I have a bunch of entries. I tried this[each.key] but that didn't work out.

Comment: If `var.olb_association` has the exact same keys as `var.vm_details` that would work. Otherwise you may need to pull it from the value. I can't see enough of your code to make a recommendation.